# MySQL join and pivot table

Tags: mysql, pivot

tbl_orders

```
order_id, qty
123, 2
124, 1
125, 3
126, 1
127, 1
128, 1
129, 4
```

tbl_score

```
order_id, name, created
123, product 1, 2018-06-01
124, product 1, 2018-06-01
125, product 1, 2018-06-02
126, product 3, 2018-06-02
127, product 2, 2018-06-03
128, product 3, 2018-06-03
129, product 3, 2018-06-03
```

Required output

```
             2018-06-01       2018-06-02        2018-06-03
product 1        3                  3               0
product 2        0                  0               1
product 3        0                  1               5
```

The following query produces the required output for 2018-06-01 but takes around 1 min and 45 seconds to complete on the live database. If I add more dates using `case` it takes more time. Can someone help me fine tune it or perhaps suggest another solution?

```
select s.name, 
  sum( case when date(s.created) = '2018-06-01' then o.qty else 0 end ) as 'June 1'  
from tbl_score s  inner join tbl_order o 
 on s.order_id=o.order_id group by s.name;
```

Comment: 1. How many records do you have in the table? 2. Are there indexes on `created` and `name` ? 3. How many different dates (and so columns) will you need in the final query ? The answers to those questions should go in your question.

Comment: It is often a lot more efficient to do such transformation in the application code as opposed to sql code.